# Turn off cache query in wamp

Tags: jquery, mysql, caching

I'm using wamp server and i want to turn off query cache.

I don't find any conf file in mysql.

I try to put query_cache_type = OFF in my.ini, but no difference.

How can i turn off cache ? I want to test my website speed....

Thanks.

Comment: Have you restart your mysql server?

Comment: Did you restart OR Have you restarted, Anant!

Answer (score 1):

execute the following in mysql terminal

SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 0;

See more details in the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-configuration.html).

Comment: 'click here' links are bad usability and SEO practice.

Comment: k..I dont know much about these things any way Thanks markus..!